# Request for an update on views about the Trinity doctrine as now held by the groups below

Tags: trinity

In 1986 the man who was the public face of the Worldwide Church of God, Herbert W. Armstrong, died. He wrote for its journal, *The Plain Truth*, but thereafter the new leadership saw various errors and decided to change them primarily in then accepting the Trinity doctrine. Many members stuck with Armstrong's teachings. Many others went along with the changes and that group was then called ***Grace Communion International***. It accepted the orthodox Trinity doctrine so was welcomed into the fold of mainstream Christianity. There were other beliefs and practices that changed but **this question is only about stances taken re. the Trinity doctrine**.

Since that major split in the Worldwide Church of God from the mid 1990s, **what is the stance re. the Trinity of those groups listed below that rejected the others’ acceptance of the Trinity doctrine** that prompted the initial dissenting group’s stance? ***Did all those others reject the Trinity doctrine, and still reject it*** (if they continue to exist separately, or if they have merged with other groups?) Failing ability to detail the current stance of all those groups re. the Trinity, ***an over-view of a few would suffice.***

The Philadelphia Church of God  (Gerald Flurry)

The Restored Church of God  (David C. Pack)

Living Church of God  (Roderick C. Meredith)

Intercontinental Church of God  (Garner Ted Armstrong)

United Church of God, an International Association

Church of God’s Faithful  (Robert G. Ardis)

Independent Church of God  (Ronald L. Dart)

Church of God, an International Community  (David Hulme)

Christian Biblical Church of God  (Fred R. Coulter)

The Church of God - PKG  (Ronald Weinland)

House of Yahweh  (Yisrayl Hawkins)

God’s Church, Worldwide  (David Moore)

Church of God, Faithful Flock  (Alton Billingsley, a.k.a., Don Billingsley)

Church of God, a Worldwide Association

Comment: According to my research I'm not sure if every group named denies the Trinity teaching but I found the following video by the Church of God who denies the Trinity saying it is pagan. The video was done as recently as 2021. According to my research I do not know that all of these groups reject the Trinity. However, as late as 2021 the Church of God put out this video rejecting the Trinity teaching and calling it "pagan." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv68A5XEOWE You can scroll to the very end for its conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the death of Hebert W. Armstrong, the Worldwide Church of God began to embrace a more orthodox understanding of the Christian faith. Armstrong’s successors, Joseph Tkach, Sr., and Joseph Tkach, Jr., have led the Worldwide Church of God in a more orthodox direction, rejecting British Israelism, accepting the Trinity, etc. The organization/denomination now refers to itself as Grace Communion International. A brief history of the transition from Armstrongism to Grace Communion can be found here:  https://www.gci.org/articles/a-short-history-of-grace-communion-international/

Not every Worldwide Church of God congregation became a part of Grace Communion International. Those who chose to remain more faithful to Armstrong's teachings formed ***the United Church of God (UCG)***. In 2010, another group, ***the Church of God, a Worldwide Association (COGWA)***, split off from the UCG. Both groups retain Armstrong's original denial of the Trinity.

I have been unable to find specific information on the various churches you listed, but it would seem that the two mentioned above rejected the Trinity doctrine.

The following link shows the organisational splits, but the print is so small I can't read it!  https://archive.gci.org/articles/worldwide-church-of-god-organizational-splits/